# Having trouble sorting 2 arrays together and then printing it. - C language

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I am having problem creating program that will sort each array first and then place them together and sort them. Any ideas where my program fail? 
In output it create random numbers like this:

```
4204988
3
4
4
5
5
6
7
7
8
```

As you can see there are 9 sorted numbers but I have no idea if it is array or already array sorted with array. There should be 20 numbers besides of 11 from which first 1 is not giving any sense.

```
void sort(int arr[], int howmany)
    {
        int i, switchh;
        while(1)
        {
            switchh = 0;
            for(i = 0; i < howmany - 1; i++)
            {
                if(arr[i] > arr[i + 1])
                {
                    int switching = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
                    arr[i + 1] = switching;
                    switchh = 1;
                }
            }
            if(switchh == 0)
                break;
        }
    }
    void sortt(int arrr[], int howmany)
    {
        int i, switchh;
        while(1)
        {
            switchh = 0;
            for(i = 0; i < howmany - 1; i++)
            {
                if(arrr[i] > arrr[i + 1])
                {
                    int switching = arrr[i];
                    arrr[i] = arrr[i + 1];
                    arrr[i + 1] = switching;
                    switchh = 1;
                }
            }
            if(switchh == 0)
                break;
        }
    }

    int main(void)
    {
        srand((unsigned)time(0));
        int howmany = 10;
        int arr[howmany];
        int swichh;
        int arrr[howmany];
        int i=0,j=0;
        for(i = 0; i < howmany; i++)
            arr[i] = rand() % 10 + 1;
            for(i = 0; i < howmany; i++)
            arrr[i] = rand() % 10 + 1;
        sort(arr, howmany);
        sortt(arrr, howmany);
        for( ; ; )
        {
        if (arr[i]>arrr[j])
        {
        printf("%d\n",arr[i]) ;
        i++;
    }
        else
        {
            if (arrr[j]>arr[i])
            {
                printf("%d\n",arrr[j]);
                j++;
            }
        }
        if ((i == howmany) || (j == howmany))
break;

    }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Your termination condition `if ((arr[i] || arrr[i]) == howmany)` is incorrect. You cannot switch the OR (||) and the EQUALS (==), like in English, you need to compare each counter (i, j) separately.

Comment: so you mean i have to write that if arr[i] = howmany then program has to break and if no then else if arrr[j] = howmany then it has to break as well.. I ment if one of these conditions is fullfilled program will break.. Did I get it right?

Comment: EDIT: Changed it but program is still not working... besides of 12 random numbers (10sorted and 2without sence) it now gives 10 numbers (9sorted and 1 without sence) I need it to give 20 numbers and all of them sorted..

Comment: Look: Your `arr` and `arrr` contain random data, so they might not contain anything equal to `howmany` (10). You need to compare the counters (`i`, `j`), and you need to compare each with a separate ==: `if ((i == howmany) || (j == howmany))`

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand the need to create both `sort` and `sortt` here. Wouldn't just one of these do? @DušoMorháč

Comment: Also shouldn't you initialise the variables `i` and `j` to zero before the statement `for( ; ; )`? P.S. `for( ; ; )` seems fishy too!

Comment: I updated program to what you told but now it gives 11random numbers (1 not giving any sence: 493021 and 10 sorted)

Comment: Wasn´t declaring them upside in main as int i=0,j=0; enought? I needed to declare cycle that will repeat until it sort out

Comment: @DušoMorháč No , since you have used `i` in the for loop where value of `i` gets incremented..Hence it is changed by then.

Comment: I know that 1 function for sorting is enought but i declared arr upside in it, and i need arrr as well since i have 2 arrays to sort

Comment: @DušoMorháč Correct me if am wrong, you have two arrays, say `a` and `b` having 10 elements each. You first wish to sort these individually then merge these in a sorted manner. Is that right?

Comment: I tryed to add i=0 and j=0 before for cycle but program wont even work then... It displays black display without any text..

Comment: Yes Aditi, I need to sort each of them and then sort them both together and print it into output

Comment: Ok, reseting them to 0 was working it now only displays 10 sorted numbers without numbers not giving any sence.. But still i need 20 numbers since both of arrays contain each 10 numbers.

Comment: Your program terminates as soon as one of the two arrays is exhausted. The other might still contain unused data. And please, try to understand that you do not need two identical functions to sort two arrays. If you had 1000 arrays to sort, would you write 1000 functions?

Comment: Wasn´t sure how to call sort funcion on arrr.. Thanks for your answer, it finally opened my eyes.. You know I am still begginer that learn on his own since my school programm in Pascal which is terrible program :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you don't need two `sort` functions. The basic aim of writing functions is not to be forced to write the same set of instructions repeatedly. Though I feel you need to study more about *functions* if this isn't clear to you.

And since you have `howmany` number of elements in `arr` and `arrr` , while merging them loop needs to run `2*howmany` number of times. Tell me if you don't understand anything. :)

```
 void sort(int arr[], int howmany)
        {
            int i, switchh;
            while(1)
            {
                switchh = 0;
                for(i = 0; i < howmany - 1; i++)
                {
                    if(arr[i] > arr[i + 1])
                    {
                        int switching = arr[i];
                        arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
                        arr[i + 1] = switching;
                        switchh = 1;
                    }
                }
                if(switchh == 0)
                    break;
            }
        }

        int main(void)
        {
            srand((unsigned)time(0));
            int howmany = 10;
            int arr[howmany];
            int swichh;
            int arrr[howmany];
            int i=0,j=0, count=0;
            for(i = 0; i < howmany; i++)
                arr[i] = rand() % 10 + 1;
            for(i = 0; i < howmany; i++)
                arrr[i] = rand() % 10 + 1; //since value of i has changed now
            i=0;
            sort(arr, howmany);
            sort(arrr, howmany);//currently both i and j are zero
            for( count = 0; count < 2*howmany ; count++ )
            {
                if( i > howmany-1)
                {
                    printf("%d\n",arrr[j]);
                    j++;
                } 
                else if( j > howmany-1)
                {
                    printf("%d\n",arr[i]);
                    i++;
                } 
                else if (arr[i]<arrr[j])
                {
                   printf("%d\n",arr[i]) ;
                   i++;
                }
                else
               {
                    printf("%d\n",arrr[j]);
                    j++;
               }
            }
            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: In your solution it may happen that `i` or `j`in the final loop become 10 (`howmany`), so the loop will access array elements outside the declared length. This will lead to random behaviour.

Comment: I am getting error compiling program: /In function 'main':
/[Error] 'for' loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 or C11 mode
[Note] use option -std=c99, -std=gnu99, -std=c11 or -std=gnu11 to compile your code

Comment: What was changed @AditiRawat? So I will understand it a little better :)

Comment: It also still gives me weird output: 1
3
4
4
6
7
8
9
9
9
48
1
4
4
4
6
6
6
7
8

Comment: In C11 / C99 you may declare the counter of a loop in the `for`statement (`for (int count =...`). In plain C this is not allowed.

Comment: @DušoMorháč The issue was in my for loop where `for( int count = 0; count < 2*howmany ; count++ )`  I had declared `count` inside of the loop which as the error states is only allowed in C99 or C11. I have changed it and also incorporated Renardo's comment.

Comment: In your last edition of program there is undeclared "n"

Comment: It gives me 20 numbers now but they are not sorted right 2
5
7
9
9
9
10
10
10
10
1
3
3
4
4
5
7
7
9
9

Comment: It looks like the arrays are sorted in ascending order, and in your final loop you are incrementing the counter of the larger side, thus making the value of this side even larger. The comparison should be inverted.

Comment: @Renardo what does that mean?

Comment: @DušoMorháč I have edited the answer. The issue was `else if (arr[i]>arrr[j])` in place of `else if (arr[i]<arrr[j])`

Comment: It works now 10++++++++ thanks man, now I need to check it out a little more to understand it properly to be able to use it in future... You really saved me.. I owe you one!